# Updating version numbers before git commit using OS X Bash sed

Tags: regex, git, bash, sed, lua

I wish to use `git log --oneline | wc -l` to provide the revision number for `sed` substitution in the following Lua file (simplified) during each commit using a script and $GIT/hooks:

```
-- settings.lua

local module = {}

    -- major, minor, build, and revision number
    module.version = "10.0.0.0"

return module
```

I'm testing from the command-line with this:

```
sed -E 's/(version\s*=\s*\"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)/\1foo"/' settings.lua
```

All `sed` outputs is the following verbatim copy of the input:

```
-- settings.lua

local module = {}

    -- major, minor, build, and revision number
    module.version = "10.0.0.0"

return module
```

I must be totally misunderstanding the things I'm ready about `sed` and its purpose in life.  Coming from a 20 years background C/C++ and in now C# I'm amazed I can't get my head around this.  I know that pattern matches!

My `sed` understanding is that it will match `version = "10.0.0.0"` and then change the entire matched string to `version = "10.0.0.foo"` which once done I can simple " and a `> settings.au` to replace the original file with the substation in place.

*As usual I've drifted way too far off track thinking something was going to be simple but wasn't and **just** because I want it.  I was really enjoying the Lua part too.*

Answer (score 1):

In `sed`, `\d` wouldn't work the way you expect it to work. Use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d`

**EDIT**

Another way to do it:

```
sed -i.bak '/module.version/s/"$/foo"/' File

AMD$ cat File
-- settings.lua

local module = {}

    -- major, minor, build, and revision number
    module.version = "10.0.0.0foo"

return module
```

For lines matching `module.version`, substitute the last `"` with `foo"`.
The above command will edit the file inplace, keeping a backup.

Comment: That did occur to me and I was using `[[:digit:]]` but felt it too verbose and had the concept all wrong at the time.  I was creating a capture group on the revision number and was hoping to just substitute that.  Is that even possible?.  I'll give the `[0-9]` a try shortly.  Thank you!  I'll come back and mark the question answered once tested.

Comment: Sorry I had to put this to one side and don't have the time to think about it properly :(  I need to replace the last digit with the one provided by `git log --oneline | wc -l`.  I getting better with sed each time I find a use for it so when time allows I'll fix it.